# Displaying many Action keys on soft-key on Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am relatively new to Android development. My requirement is such that I have a multiple line input box(such as comment box); as the user clicks the box a soft-key keyboard appears on screen which has either an "Enter" button or "Next" Button as an Action key.

I want the keyboard to have both, "Enter" as well as "Next" Button and also the comma(,) button.

I have searched throughout the web. They only have options to specify the "android:imeOptions" tag. But this option does not give the desired output as I need.

Kindly help.

PS: I do not want to create a custom keyboard. Just want to modify the existing soft-key keyboard to be displayed.

Also, I am working on Android v2.2

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the keyboard to have both, "Enter" as well as "Next" Button and also the comma(,) button.

There is, at most, one action key for an input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard). You cannot have two. Depending on the input method editor, you may have zero, as the input method editor is not obligated to show an action key.

Comment: Is it possible to explicitly display the Comma(,) key? Some Android device show in their soft-keypad and some don't. I wish the Comma(,) key to be displayed in all the devices

Comment: @RaviJayaraman: "Is it possible to explicitly display the Comma(,) key?" -- no.